# How to have equal size faces

Tags: modeling, add-on

Is it possible to have all the faces exact size without losing the shape of the mesh. With or without addon. With the Looptool adon we can have equal spacing in the verts.

[image]

[image]

My mesh was subdivided and applied. How can i have equal size of faces all over the mesh. In my model top faces are small bottom are big. Any suggestion . Thanks

Comment: [Manual retopo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM) is the cleanest way to achieve that. Alternatively try the new [volume remesh workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k1KSJxIfHE) to get even sized quads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you have a reason to make your loops *exactly* equidistant, if so, I've missed, with this one.. This is really to *reduce* geometry, while preserving curvature.

Enable the shipped Add-on '*Simplify Curves*' and..

1. Select, duplicate, and make a new object of one vertical half-loop from your cone (BTW, straighten it out in your chosen plane, and make sure it has verts at directly above and below the object origin)
2. Convert the profile to a Curve
3. Call up 'Simplify Curve' from your F3 search menu and tweak to acceptable preservation of curvature
4. Convert the profile back to a mesh, and *Screw* modifier turn it back into a cone.

[image]

You can save a lot of polygons..

[image]

Without *that* much difference in curvature .. (both examples subdivided once) and if you want to keep the shape flexible, Curves can be given a *Screw* modifier, before conversion.

This .blend includes some discretionary manual edits to the profile just before spinning .. bevelling vertices at very sharp corners to hold up under subdiv. The simplifying step is from 'Plane_005' to 'Simple_Plane_005'.

[image]

Comment: I having 2 issue. 1st followed the steps till f3 search, after converting curve in f3 search simplify curve pop, next what. 2nd after adding screw modifier some face are flip i try to recalculate normals but did not working doing manually will take lot time. any addon to make it automatic flip normals . https://imgur.com/a/DtDfOn0. Thanks

Comment: Hi @atek. When you use _Simplify Curve_, it creates a duplicate with the name prefix `simple`. It looks as if you've joined the duplicates and spun them together? The _Screw_ modifier has a 'Recalc Normals' and 'Flip' setting.. always check whether they need to be used. _Simplify Curve_ gives you a (F9) Adjust Last Operation panel, tweak the 'Error' while eyeballing. I've included a breakdown in a .blend. See Edit.

Answer (score 4):

**1st** - Original / **2nd** - Un-Subdivide 2 / **3rd** + Delete Disolve Edge (manually selected loops)

[image]

But as Robin Betts answer - separate profile curvature and use Screw modifier choice.